# Laravel array sum of fields validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm new to Laravel where I'm using Laravel's validator for a project not built in Laravel.

I need to know if there is a simple built in Laravel validator to validate the sum of a certain field in all of the objects in an array.

My input looks something like:

```
{
    "customer":95,
    "name": "My object",
    "values":
        [
        { 
            "name": "AAA",
            "percentage": 50
        },
        {
            "name": "BBB",
            "percentage": 50
        }
    ]

}
```

I need to make sure that the sum of my percentages is 100. Is there a simple way?

Comment: Take a look at this gist : https://gist.github.com/martinbean/b21e6bf5f5d75ffa9244b4bf530ea81e

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules) for single attribute validations.

Use [After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#after-validation-hook) for other or more complex validations, say the sum of multiple fields.

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if ($this->get('field1') + $this->get('field2') + $this->get('field3') != 100) {
            $validator->errors()->add(null, 'The sum of field1, field2 and field3 must be 100');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be best for you to create a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules). In the validation, I'd convert the values array to a collection and use the [collection sum method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sum). E.g.:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $values = collect($value);

    return $values->sum('percentage') <= 100;
}
```

Comment: See this if you want to pass a parameter to `passes()`: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/create-custom-validation-rule-with-additional-parameters-implement-in-request

Comment: gud idea, but why collect and sum, can't we use array_sum? any thoughts?

Comment: I did not test it, but array_sum might actually be faster than what I put in here back in 2018, since it does not require you to map the array set to a collection. So I think your suggestion is valid.